# Transforming executables, objects or binaries between different architectures

Tags: c, assembly, architecture, compiler-construction, disassembly

Beforehand: This is just a nasty idea I had this night :-)

Think about the following scenario:

You have some arm-elf executable and for some reasons you want to run it on your amd64 box without emulating.
To simplify the scenario, let's say we just want to deal with simple console applications which are just linked against libc and there are no additional architecture specific requirements.

If you want to transform binaries between different architectures you have to consider the following points:

- Endianess of the architectures
- bit-width of registers
- functionality of different registers

Endianess should be one of the lesser problems.
If the bit-width of the destination registers is smaller then those of the source architecture one could insert additional instructions to represent the same behaviour. The same applies to the functionality of registers.

Finally, (and before bashing down this idea), have a look at the following **simple** code snippet and its corresponding disassembly of the objects.

[C Code](http://pastebin.com/c1z2Lje1)

[Corresponding ARM Disassembly](http://pastebin.com/qaNYY0WM)

[Corresponding AMD64 Disassembly](http://pastebin.com/ivknkFCG)

In my opinion it **should** be possible to convert those objects between different architectures. Even function calls (like printf) could be mapped or wrapped to the destination architecture's libc.

And now my questions:
Did anyone already think about realising this?

Is it actually possible?

Are there already some projects dealing with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has been done. It's often called "binary translation", and perhaps the most famous use was in Intel based Macs to run PPC executables. It's mostly done dynamically, because statically you don't really know for sure what parts of the program are going to execute (may include data, even dynamic data).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation